# OCR implementation using using java

Tags: java

I have written java code to convert images into text using java.But my code is taking only single image as input . I want that the program should fetch images from a folder and then run the OCR on it.

My code is:

```
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
 import org.junit.Test;

 import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.*;
 import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract.*;
 import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

 import java.io.File;


 public class BasicTesseractExampleTest {


@Test
public void givenTessBaseApi_whenImageOcrd_thenTextDisplayed() throws Exception {
    BytePointer outText;

    TessBaseAPI api = new TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api.Init(".", "ENG") != 0) {
        System.err.println("Could not initialize tesseract.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    PIX image = pixRead("IMG_0012 (1).jpg");
    api.SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api.GetUTF8Text();
    String string = outText.getString();
    assertTrue(!string.isEmpty())  

  System.out.println(str);


    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api.End();
    outText.deallocate();
    pixDestroy(image);


}
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Getting below error on the same code: OS: mac .   Error opening data file /Users/saudet/projects/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tesseract/cppbuild/macosx-x86_64/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.

Answer (score -1):

To read a list of files out of a given Path use for example:

```
File f = new File("C:/programs");
File[] fileArray = f.listFiles();
```

Now you can check every File out of the `fileArray` if it is a directory and skip that with:

```
if(fileArray[0].isDirectory()) continue;
```

To find the images you can check for example the ending of the filename with:

```
fileArray[0].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
```

Do this check for all files out ouf the `fileArray` and call your method with the right files. To check the right file you have to change this line of your code:

```
PIX image = pixRead("IMG_0012 (1).jpg");
```

and add the `fileArray[?]` where the `?` must be replaced with the right number.

Comment: When I change the line of code in the following way:                             for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
         {
             if(fileArray[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg"))
             {
                 PIX image = pixRead(fileArray[i]);
         }                                                                                                       I got the error    :     no suitable method found for pixRead(File)
    method lept.pixRead(BytePointer) is not applicable

Comment: Please use: `pixRead(fileArray[i].getPath());` or `pixRead(fileArray[i].getName());` what you need in this function.